# An algebraic approach to the analyticity of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

Famously, complex analysis is much "nicer" (more rigid) than real analysis. The reason for this is that, as I like to put it, complex analysis is just one-dimensional algebraic geometry. This is formalized via GAGA, but the fundamental fact that makes this work is that holomorphic functions are always analytic. As a result, we have a fundamental sequence of inclusions $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]_{(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)}\subset\mathbb{C}\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}\subset\mathbb{C}[[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]]$ which allows us to work with holomorphic functions algebraically. We find that holomorphic germs form a regular local ring of dimension $n$, admit a division algorithm (Weierstrass preparation theorem), and so on.

As for *why* holomorphic functions are analytic, however, the standard proof involves expanding the inside of a path integral. This isn't exactly surprising—after all, $\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic object, so the proof ought to use analysis. In terms of the intuition behind this, though, the best I've been able to find is "holomorphic functions satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations". My problem with this is that it's based on differential equations over $\mathbb{R}$, rather than using the basic properties of $\mathbb{C}$ itself (minimal algebraically closed complete Archimedean field).

In general, suppose we have a topological field $K$, or a field with absolute value if you like. We can define a perfectly good theory of differentiability for functions on open subsets of affine space $K^n$, and we get a theory of smooth functions, analytic functions, and manifolds. From a purely algebreo-geometric point of view, we can always work with varieties over $K$, and we can do calculus on them algebraically. Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, we should be able to naturally make the set of $K$-points of any smooth variety into a $K$-manifold. This is typically done over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, the $p$-adic numbers (and their algebraic extensions), and more generally fields with a complete absolute value. So my question is as follows: what conditions on $K$ will make it so that the smooth theory of $K$-manifolds will be describable, at least approximately, via the algebraic one? What will cause the smooth functions to be analytic? And, in particular, what properties of $\mathbb{C}$ allow its theory of smooth functions to be described algebraically from this perspective?

Comment: In my opinion this question is slightly misguided.  Namely, it's only true that holomorphic functions are LOCALLY representable as power series. For any open domain in $\mathbb{C}$ there are holomorphic functions which are not power series. This already puts a kaibosh on the 'algebraicity' in any real global sense. That said, something in the positive direction. Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a ringed space over a characteristic $0$ field $k$ with the property that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is Noetherian with residue field $k$ for all points $x$ of $X$ (e.g. $X$ is a complex manifold

Comment: or $X$ is complex algebraic variety in classical language). Then, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ embeds into its completion $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$. If one assumes further that all the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are regular, then the Cohen structure theorem then implies that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}\cong k[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ for some $n$. Thus the embedding $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}\cong k[x_1,...,x_n]$ says that 'every function on $X$ is locally representable in power series' (i.e. locally analytic). Thus, perhaps the answer to your question is: one needs

Comment: regular Noetherian local rings (something shared by smooth complex algebraic varieties in classical language, and complex manifolds). PS, the other part I feel slightly misguided is to say that 'complex analysis is one-dimensional algebraic geometry' -- it's nice idea, and there are strong ties between the two, but they are very different. In particular, GAGA only applies (in the one-dimensional case) to compact Riemann surfaces which are, it seems to me, the opposite of what you are implicitly treating as the basic objects of complex analysis (open domains in $\mathbb{C}$).